# Get all fields for a given content type including title

Tags: entities

I'm using field_info_instances($entity,$bundle) to read through every field in a given content type in their weighted order. However, field_info_instances does not include the node title. Why not and how can I remedy it so its added to the $fields array for sorting and processing in this scenario:

```
<?php 
function do_something($content_type){
    $fields = field_info_instances("node",$content_type);
    usort($fields,"sort_stuff");
    foreach($fields as $field_name=>$value){
        do_something($value);
    }
}

function sort_stuff($a,$b){
    return $a['widget']['weight']-$b['widget']['weight'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The node title is not a field handled from the field API. If you want to know if a content type has a title, you can use the following code.

```
$types = node_type_get_types();

if (isset($types[$content_type]) && $types[$content_type]->has_title) {
  $title = $types[$content_type]->title_label;
}
```

The code you are looking for is the same code used by Drupal to sort the fields (and extra fields) in admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields.

[image: screenshot]

The function that handles that page is [field_ui_field_overview_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field_ui!field_ui.admin.inc/function/field_ui_field_overview_form/7).

Basing on the code of that function, I wrote the code you would need to get the list of fields, and extra fields, with their label, and weight.

```
  $fields = array();
  $instances = field_info_instances('node', $content_type);
  $extra_fields = field_info_extra_fields('node', $content_type, 'form');

  // Fields.
  foreach ($instances as $name => $instance) {
    $field = field_info_field($instance['field_name']);
    $fields[$instance['field_name']] = array(
      'title' => $instance['label'],
      'weight' => $instance['widget']['weight'],
    );
  }

  // Non-field elements.
  foreach ($extra_fields as $name => $extra_field) {
    $fields[$name] = array(
      'title' => $extra_field['label'],
      'weight' => $extra_field['weight'],
    );
  }
```

Notice that the extra fields don't contain just the title, but every extra field for which a module returned information in [hook_field_extra_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7). There are modules that add fields to the node editing form, and implement `hook_field_extra_fields()` to allow the users with the right permission to decide the order in which their fields appear. For example, if you have installed the [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom) module, the page I shown in the previous screenshot becomes the following one.

[image: screenshot]

Notice also that it is easy to notice which fields are not implemented using the field API if you look at admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields: For those fields, the Field column doesn't contain a link. That is what happens for the fields labelled Title, and Mollom.